# "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into `news`

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

So, I am currently encountering with this error, the problem is when I want to create a new record this error occurs but when I update nothing happens, my DB is MySql and it is set to utf8, I have one local and one currently deployed, the one that I am deploying has utf8 but the local one has utf8mb4 I've looked at other questions similar to mine but I don't think they have the same solution.

> SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime
>   value: '2018' for column 'created_at' at row 1 (SQL: insert into
>   `news` (`title`, `description`, `date`, `pictures`, `categroy_id`,
>   `updated_at`, `created_at`) values (zxczx,
>
> xzxczxc
>
> , 09/28/2018,
>   ["3_1538054794.jpg"], 6, 2018-09-27 13:26:34, 2018-09-27 13:26:34))

and that's how I save it

```
    $new = new News;

    $new->title = $input['title'];
    $new->description = $input['description'];
    $new->date = $input['date'];
    $new->pictures = json_encode($pics);
    $new->categroy_id = $input['category'];
    $new->save();
```

Comment: So `$input['date']` is `2018`, which is a year, not a date time?

Comment: what's the value of $input['date'] ?

Comment: What is the data type for "date" column?

Comment: Can you please share the Table structure?

Comment: @JonStirling @KrishnaJoshi The error appears to relate to the `created_at` field, not the `date` field. `created_at` is something automatically populated by Eloquent models when creating.

Comment: Did you by chance create any kind of mutators for the `created_at` attribute? Something like `setCreatedAtAttribute` where you change the behaviour of `created_at` at the moment of saving?

Comment: try  `created_at = \Carbon::now();`

Comment: cnat edit questiin and put your migration table and try delete mb4

Answer (score 0):

You use Carbon to parse the date it will convert it to date format which is used by MySql  YYYY-m-dd

```
$new = new News;
$new->title = $input['title'];
$new->description = $input['description'];
$new->created_at = Carbon::now();
$new->pictures = json_encode($pics);
$new->categroy_id = $input['category'];
$new->save();
```

Comment: still refers to created_at

Answer (score 0):

Try like this :

```
$new = new News;
$new->title = $input['title'];
$new->description = $input['description'];
$new->pictures = json_encode($pics);
$new->date = $input['date'];
$new->categroy_id = $input['category'];
$new->created_at = new \DateTime();
$new->save();
```

Comment: still refers to created_at

Comment: class News extends Model
{
    public function category(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Categroy');
    }
}

Comment: "SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1292 Incorrect datetime value: '2018' for column 'updated_at' at row 1 This occurred I tried the same way you fixed but didn't workedcreated_at $new = new News;
        $new->title = $input['title'];
        $new->description = $input['description'];
        $new->pictures = json_encode($pics);
        $new->categroy_id = $input['category'];
        $new->date = $input['date'];
        $new->created_at = new \DateTime();
        $new->updated_at = new \DateTime();
        $new->save();

Comment: maybe you have set the default value as '2018' for 'created_at' and 'updated_at' columns. check that.